# Ruby/Rails - call class method from external class definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a "hub and spoke" class relationship model where one class is the center and it needs to be aware of an arbitrary number of spoke classes.  I'm designing the Hub class to be part of a gem, and I want the spokes to be defined by the user of that gem.  Because of that, I can't define the spokes within the hub class, I have to leave it up to the user to define and register the spoke.  I tried this, with no luck:

```
# models/hub.rb
class Hub
  @@spokes = []

  def self.spokes
    @@spokes
  end

  def self.register_spoke spoke
    @@spokes << spoke
  end
end

# models/spoke.rb
class Spoke
end

Hub.register_spoke 'Spoke'
```

This works if you just run it, but I want this relationship to get set up at load-time within a Rails app, and I can't seem to get that to work.  Help?

Comment: is hub.rb or whatever has this code located under the models folder in your Rails app?

Comment: yes, and the "register_spoke" call is at the bottom of spoke.rb

Comment: I put that code into a Rails app and it worked as expected.

Comment: do a rails console

Comment: Then do Hub.spokes it should return the array with one item

Comment: If you are in a web app... restart the server so that everything under models folder is loaded

Comment: Although I think it should be reloaded anyway in developement

Comment: @slindsey3000: as I mentioned, that code works if you just run it (from a Rails console), but if I put the two classes into separate model files and run the console, `Hub.spokes` returns `[]` for me.

Comment: maybe require 'hub' at the top of spoke.rb?

Comment: I actually managed to get it working if I do the `register_spoke` call from within an initializer, which is probably the right way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you wanted to make the Hub a part of a gem. In that case you can just define an initializer where you would call `Hub.register_spoke 'Spoke'`. You can do this in `config/initializers/hub.rb`

Comment: Yep, I just replied to @slindsey3000 with this.  Good call.